# In Xcode 8: How to set default phone type for main.storyboard and active scheme for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently in `XCode 8.3` whenever I created a new project. The default phone type for `Main.Storyboard` (lower left: View As ) is `iPhone 7`.  And the default phone type on active Scheme (top left on `XCode` main screen) is `iPhone 7 Plus`.

Is there a way to configure default phone type for both. So every time I create a new `XCode iOS` project, it always started with the same type I defined. (e.g. both `iPhone SE`).

I've searched for information related to this but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the one on the top left:

Product > Destination > Add Additinal Simulators
Then choose simulators in "Devices / Simulators"

And select each phone you don't want and uncheck "Show as run destination"

You need to do this for all phones under Iphone SE in case you want to use that one like i did. Just keep uncheking until the Xcode selects the phone you want by itself.

As for the one in the storyboard, i am still trying to solve that one myself.